# ClassNotFoundException: clojure.algo.monads

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm trying require clojure.algo.monads, I'm a little confused with clojure import/require/use

```
; at lein...
:main monads.core/-main
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [org.clojure/algo.monads "0.1.5"]])
```

install deps: lein deps

and this simpele code to test

```
(ns monads.core
  (require clojure.algo.monads))


(defn -main [& args]
  (clojure.algo.monads)
  (println "Hello, World!"))
```

lein run

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: clojure.algo.monads, compiling:(monads/core.clj:6:3)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6464)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyze(Compiler.java:6406)
at clojure.lang.Compiler$InvokeExpr.parse(Compiler.java:3665)
at clojure.lang.Compiler.analyzeSeq(Compiler.java:6646)
...
```

I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `(clojure.algo.monads)` in your `-main` function is considered a call to `clojure.algo.monads`, which should be either a special form, a macro, or a function. However, `clojure.algo.monads` is a namespace. There is no Java class file corresponding to it. This results in `ClassNotFoundException`.

I suggest that you require the `clojure.algo.monads` namespace and refer only limited functions or macros that you want to use. Here is an example.

```
user> (require '[clojure.algo.monads :refer [domonad maybe-m]])
nil

user> (defn f
        [x]
        (domonad maybe-m
                 [a x
                  b (inc x)]
                 (* a b)))
#'user/f

user> (f 3)
12

user> (f nil)
nil
```